# Is there a way to check if a custom form element exists in application

Tags: 7, forms

Suppose i am building a custom form element with

> hook_element_info()

Is there a way , in another module,to check this element's existence before inserting it to a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the hook yourself to check for the existence of a specific element type:

```
if (in_array('some_element_key', array_keys(module_invoke_all('element_info')))) {
  // The element type exists.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, im pretty sure this will work, but as i tried with system_element_info(), i see that it runs before my hook_element_info() and does not contain my custom element, any logic to that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The above code will give you all of the element types defined in the system, including any defined in custom modules

Comment: So the system_element_info() will give me only the system-provided ones? thats all..

Comment: Yep, each module defines its own element types using this hook

Comment: Good to clear that out, cheers

Comment: @PanChrono system is a module, just one provided by core that you can't disable.  There really isn't anything terribly special about it.